# JQuery Datatable with Scroller enabled and Bootstrap5 styling is causing unexpected vertical scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am getting a vertical scrollbar in the jquery datatable even for just 2 records. Please refer the jsfiddle link below,

[image: Vertical Scrollbar in Datatable]

https://jsfiddle.net/xwLb79h6/7/

I am using bootstrap 5 and latest version of jquery datatable.

HTML:

```
<table id="example" class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped nowrap" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>        
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable({
    deferRender: true,
        scrollY: '25vh',
        scrollX: true,
        scroller: true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        searching: false,
        paging: true,
});} );
```

When I removed the table-bordered class, it seems like the scrollbar is going away. However, I need the table-bordered class.

I am wondering why the vertical scrollbar is appearing for just 2 records and how to avoid it.
Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check in developer tools, it's because <tr style='height:2px;'> ... it's beetween top menu of table and first td ... but why it give such behavior ... if I remove it, there is problem with width of table ... you must find solution :)

Comment: @Wordica I noticed the same and applied the fix. Thank you looking at this issue.

Comment: no problem, good luck ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noticed a 2px getting added in table head tr. I am able to fix the issue by removing the 2px height in table head tr.

Fixed here: https://jsfiddle.net/xwLb79h6/11/

CSS change:

```
.table.dataTable > thead > tr{
  height:0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the scroll y & x value in Java script code than check.

```
   ****scrollY: '25vh',
    scrollX: true,****
```

Comment: I cannot remove the scollY and scrollx. ScrollY will set the max height value.